# Why isn't method formatting Python dictionary key indenting?

Tags: python

For some reason method formatting a dictionary key only begins to indent after specifying a width greater than 4. Any idea why?

```
for i in range(10):
    print({'{0:>{1}}'.format('test',i):12}, "should be indented", i)
```

Output:

```
{'test': 12} should be indented 0
{'test': 12} should be indented 1
{'test': 12} should be indented 2
{'test': 12} should be indented 3
{'test': 12} should be indented 4
{' test': 12} should be indented 5
{'  test': 12} should be indented 6
{'   test': 12} should be indented 7
{'    test': 12} should be indented 8
{'     test': 12} should be indented 9
```

Also, when I try to output a dictionary with indented keys to a text document the indent isn't consistent. For example, when I specify a constant indentation width of 10 characters, the indentation is not consistent across the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dict keys, nor is there anything special about the number 4; it just happens to be the length of your string `"test"`.

With [`{0:>{1}}`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) you say that that entire block should be right-aligned to a total length of at least `{1}` characters, *including* the string you passed as `{0}`. So if `{1}` is `6`, and `{0}` is `"test"`, then the string is padded with two spaces, for a total length of 6.

```
In [11]: "{0:>{1}}".format("test", 6)
Out[11]: '  test'
```

This is similar to what `str.rjust` does:

```
In [12]: "test".rjust(6)
Out[12]: '  test'
```

If you want a constant padding independent of the string's original length, you can, e.g., use string multiplication, or use a more complex format string, padding an empty string to some given length before putting your actual string.

```
In [14]: " " * 6 + "test"
Out[14]: '      test'
In [15]: "{2:{1}}{0}".format("test", 6, "")
Out[15]: '      test'
```